# Building a Vector Tile API from a netCDF file

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, netcdf, vector-tiles

### Objective

I am trying to create a Vector Tile API (in javascript) that can be used in a react application using the mapbox-gl library.
Expected endpoint: `url/{tileset_id}/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.{format}`.

I only have a netCDF file for the moment.

### My approach

From what I currently understand, I need to convert my netCDF file to Vector Tiles (perhaps using TileServer GC), then serve those tiles on an API (perhaps using Tippecanoe). Is this the best way to proceed or is there a simpler solution?

I'm not necessarily waiting for specific answers, but rather some possible leads / solutions to achieve this goal.